# icon badge not appear in IOS 10 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I expect to see a bubble icon badge number after clicking the button that should set a bubble number of app icon - but-  I dont see any numbered bubble in icon after pressing homebutton. my question: is icon badge not appear in ios simulator?

```
- (IBAction)btn1_click:(id)sender {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:4];
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not totally intuitive, but your app must first receive permission to handle notifications with `UNUserNotificationCenter` [requestAuthorizationWithOptions:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649527-requestauthorizationwithoptions?language=objc)

```
// import with *one of*...
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
@import UserNotifications;

UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:UNAuthorizationOptionBadge completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted) {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 4;
    }
}];
```

The badge is sort of user interaction -- associated with notifications -- that must be authorized.

Answer (score 3):

You should also set the badge on the main thread - I'm getting a warning with the code above.

This works in Swift:

```
private func badgeTest() {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: .badge) { (granted, error) in
    if granted {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 4
      }
    }
  }
```